# If Media Type .GIF

Tags: images, timthumb

Been looking for a way to do this but cant seem to find anything, not even here.

I am using timthumb to re-size my sites images. As most of you know after re-sizing a animated gif its not going to work any more. So i need a way to skip over the image if its a .gif file type. Something like

```
<?php if( typegif() ) { ?>
<img src="<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'full' ); echo $src[0]; ?>" alt="Image# <?php the_ID(); ?> "/> 
 <?php } else { ?>
 <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/thumbs/timthumb.php?src=<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); echo $src[0]; ?>&w=280" alt="Image# <?php the_ID(); ?> "/> 
 <?php } ?>
```

After some more digging i found this code, however its not working.

```
  $attachment_mime = wp_check_filetype(wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID) );
   if ( $attachment_mime['type'] == 'image/gif') { 
       echo 'this is gif';
       }
       else {
       echo 'this aint gif';
       }
```

Comment: Wow did i find a question no one can answer lol

Comment: If i misspelled the title wrong 5 people would have done commented by now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure you're using the `wp_check_filetype()` correctly. I just successfully tried the following to determine if the post thumbnail ext was jpg or not:

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( ) );
$filetype = wp_check_filetype($url);
    if ($filetype[ext] == 'jpg') {
        echo 'this is gif';
    }
    else {
       echo 'this aint gif';
    }
```

You probably know already but if you ever want to see what the function returns, you can use `echo print_r($filetype)` and it will print the returned array and you can dissect how to best use the returned information (sometimes easier than interpreting up the codex!)